# JQuery AJAX load() & ready()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load, ready

My main HTML file dynamically loads in content with;

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Loading please wait
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').load("remotePage.html");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

remotePage.html is;

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function init(){
    someFunctionThatDependsOnAllScripts();   //Fails because all scripts is not yet loaded
  }

  $(document).ready(init);

<script>
</body>
</html>
```

It fails because the ready in script1.js is called before script1.js is loaded.
Having a callback on load doesn't seem to help.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').load("remotePage.html", function(){
    init();  //doesn't work either
  });
});
```

How can I tell when all ajax operations for loading in resources required by remotePage.html having finished?
How to fix?

Thanks

Comment: You have to include the jQuery library first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change script tag to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js" onload="init()"></script>
```

And remove 
  `$(init);` method from your script.

**UPDATED:** If you had multiple scripts to include then you can use something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js" onload="scriptLoaded()"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js" onload="scriptLoaded()"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js" onload="scriptLoaded()"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //
   var totalScriptsToLoad = 3;
   function scriptLoaded(){
        if(--totalScriptsToLoad == 0){
             init();
        }
   }
   //
   function init(){
       someFunctionFromScript1();   //Fails because script1 is not yet loaded
   }

<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about if I've got 10 scripts?

Comment: Also if possible I'd like to try and do this without editing remotePage.html as that page is available itself and end target.

Comment: I have updated my code. See the answer for '3 scripts'. '10 scripts' is similar.

Comment: That would work, I need to edit remotePage.html but I can live with that, you've definitely answered my question thanks :)